# how do i make a subroutine run if a different subroutine doesnt run

Tags: python-3.5

how do i make a subroutine run if a different subroutine doesnt run? i want the irst subroutine to run and if it doesnt the the second subroutine will run. the task i am trying to do is if the registration is not in my csv file then the program will ask the user to input the drivers details in the textfile

```
import time
import csv

def Matching_Registrations():
    reading_csv=open('details_of_drivers.csv','rt')
    matching_registrations=csv.reader(reading_csv)
    for row in matching_registrations:
        for colunm in row:
            if colunm==Reg1:
                print('A fine will be sent out to this person\'s details')
                print('This is the individuals record:\n')
                print('First name: '+row[0])
                print('Surname: '+row[1])
                print('Date of birth: '+row[2])
                print('Gender: '+row[5])
                print('email: '+row[3])
                print('Adress: '+row[4])
                print('Registration plate: '+row[6]+'\n')


def Details_in_textFile():
        reading_csv=open('details_of_drivers.csv','rt')
        Details_in_textFile=csv.reader(reading_csv)
        for row in Details_in_textFile:
                for colunm in row:
                    print('please enter the details of the driver who has been speeding and is not in the database')
                    name=input('please enter the first name: ')
                    surname=input('please enter the surname: ')
                    DOB=input('please enter the Date of birth: ')
                    gender=input('please enter the gender: ')
                    email=input('please enter the email: ')
                    adress=input('please enter the adress: ')
                    registration=input('please enter the Registration plate: ')
                    file=open('details of drivers.txt','w' )
                    file.write(name+'\n'+surname+'\n'+DOB+'\n'+gender+'\n'+email+'\n'+adress+'\n'+registration)
                    file.close()
                    print('This driver was not in the database')







speed_limit_KMH=70
road_length_km=0.1
Reg1=input("Enter registration number: ")
start = time.clock()

Reg2=input("Enter second Regestration: ")

time= (time.clock() - start)

time=time/3600

driver_speed=int(road_length_km/time)

if Reg1==Reg2:

    if driver_speed>speed_limit_KMH:
        print('The driver went over the speed limit, the speed was '+(str(driver_speed))+'KPH\n')
        Matching_Registrations()
        #dont know what to do  
        Details_in_textFile()
    if driver_speed<speed_limit_KMH:
        print('The driver was driving below the speed limit, the speed was '+(str(driver_speed))+'KPH' )
    if driver_speed==speed_limit_KMH:
        print('The driver was driving on the speed limit, the speed was '+(str(driver_speed))+'KPH' )
    print('the speed limit was '+(str(speed_limit_KMH))+'KPH\n')

else:
    print('Regestrations are not a match')
```

Comment: also the second subroutine keeps looping and wont stop

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to detect things did not work, then to pass some kind of "success/failure" response from your first function (at least), so your "main" routine can decide whether it needs to run the second function.

You could set a boolean to False, change it to True if you find a match and return this

```
def Matching_Registrations():
    matched = False
    ...
            if colunm==Reg1:
                matched=True
                ...
    ...
    return matched
```

then you could call the functions doing something like

```
if not Matching_Registrations():
    Details_in_textFile()
```

You could call the second function from within the first instead of returning a boolean, but this would be very hard to read.